# Meaning of 気持ちを通わせていった

Tags: meaning

My question is about phrases like 心を通わせる, etc which use 通わせる. If I look up an explanation using it I will often see e.g. 心が通じ合う which makes sense to me, but I don't quite get how to understand the way the causative form of 通う is being used.

こうして、流れに身を任せるように、お互いの**気持ちを通わせていった**

Answer (score 1):

気持ちが通う：one's feeling interacts

人が気持ちを通わせる：People make their feelings interact